# Nodejs - RTSP live camera feed - distributed architecture

Tags: node.js, rtsp, nodejs-stream

We have a requirement where we pass the camera details and need to show the live stream to the end-user in a web browser. As this is distributed architecture, so we can do it using the Rest API only or socket communication.

Technology stack

1. Nodejs - at Backend
2. Angular - at frontend

As part of the solution, I found npm - node-rtsp-stream - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-stream but problem is that we have to create the API and pass the stream in api, have at least 20-30 camera to see the live stream. Pass the port from the frontend and use it at the backend.

Problem -

- How to stop the stream as the user click on the pause button, I have tried with API - '/camera/feed/stop/:port' but it is not working?
- As creating API for the stream, there is a high chance that the stream gets mixed up, and how to manage the ws port?
- Any better solution to show the stream on the client-side using the RTSP URL

I tried the below solution, but no luck

```
const Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream');
app.get('/camera/feed/:camera/:port', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.port);
    if (req.params.camera == 1) {
        var ip_address2 = "192.168.1.12"
        var username2 = "admin";
        var password2 = "admin";
    } else if (req.params.camera == 2) {
        var ip_address2 = "192.168.1.10"
        var username2 = "admin";
        var password2 = "admin";
    }
    stream = new Stream({
        streamUrl: 'rtsp://' + username2 + ':' + password2 + '@' + ip_address2 + ':554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif',
        wsPort: req.params.port
    });
    res.send('OK');
});
// Stop the stream that produce using ffmpeg
app.get('/camera/feed/stop/:port', (req, res) => {
    stream.stop() // This is not make ffmpeg to stop the processing stream 
    res.send('OK');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

index.html

```
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9999");
var player3 = new jsmpeg(websocket, { canvas: canvas3, autoplay: true, loop: true })
```

Thank you.

Comment: I found the solution. Passing the stream object in API response and this contains the PID      `res.send(stream);`  For the stop/kill the FFmpeg process we can use the PID from the frontend `kill(req.params.pid);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Passing the stream object in API response and this contains the PID `res.send(stream);` For the stop/kill the FFmpeg process we can use the PID from the frontend `kill(req.params.pid);`

Answer (score 0):

For pausing the stream, you can use the `stop()` method in player, `player3.stop()`